# Logic for getting latest filename with date for each unique index of filename in directory list

Tags: python

I am still relatively new to Python and am struggling to figure out the logic of retrieving latest filename with date for each unique index of filename in directory list. This may sound somewhat confusing but will try to explain from example list of files and and expected output below. I am not looking for the code for this but rather the logic behind what I am attempting to do.

List of files in directory example as follows:

[image]

As you can see the above list of files have multiple files with the same index of first 8 characters then followed by date as yyyymmdd format - I'm basically trying to output a unique filename of index of first 8 characters but with the latest date.

Expected output as follows:

[image]

My own logic was wrong and just confusing hence asking for any advice on logical steps to take to achieve this goal. Thank you

Comment: SO isn't a coding service.  Show the code you have written (e.g. "My own logic was wrong") and any errors or incorrect output along with desired output.  Read the [mcve] guidelines.  Also place any text in the question as *text*, not images, for easy copy/paste for testing.

Comment: @MarkTolonen To be fair, OP does state "I am not looking for the code for this..."

Comment: @CtrlZ So why did you post the code for this? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary. The keys will be the first 8 characters of each filename. The associated value will be a list for strings based on the remaining characters of each filename - i.e., from offset 8 onwards. You can then iterate over the dictionary items and sort each value (list) to determine what value you're interested in

```
from collections import defaultdict

files = [
    "AE_DIFX_20240320.zip",
    "AE_DIFX_20240321.zip",
    "AE_DIFX_20240322.zip",
    "AE_BATY_20240314.zip",
    "AE_BATY_20240315.zip",
    "AE_BATY_20240316.zip",
    "ZW_XZIM_20240320.zip",
    "ZW_XZIM_20240321.zip",
    "ZW_XZIM_20240322.zip"
]

d = defaultdict(list)

for file in files:
    d[file[:8]].append(file[8:])

print(*[k + sorted(v)[-1] for k, v in d.items()], sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
AE_DIFX_20240322.zip
AE_BATY_20240316.zip
ZW_XZIM_20240322.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
The logic of my previous coding would be more confusing. So simplified the code. And the logic can be easily understood by reading the comments inside my code.

```
files = [
    'AE_DIFX_20240320.zip',
    'AE_DIFX_20240321.zip',
    'AE_DIFX_20240322.zip',
    'US_BATY_20240314.zip',
    'US_BATY_20240315.zip',
    'US_BATY_20240316.zip',
    'ZW_XZIM_20240320.zip',
    'ZW_XZIM_20240321.zip',
    'ZW_XZIM_20240322.zip']

# create a list containing first 8 characters of each file 
l = [x[:8] for x in files]

# Remove duplicates by converting into  set
l = set(l)

dct = {}

# Iterate thru list l
for x in l:

    # create an empty sub list
    sub = []
    
    # iterate over files
    for y in files:

        # to make lists of files containing same prefixes
        if x in y:
            
            sub.append(y[8:16])
            dct[x] = sub

# now the dct's keys are unique prefixes. values are lists of numbers with specific prefix
# But we want only the largest of numbers for each prefix(latest date)

#concatenate key, max(value) and .zip

ls = [f'{k}{max(v)}.zip' for k, v in dct.items()]

# Sort
ls = sorted(ls)
print(ls)

# Output: ['AE_DIFX_20240322.zip', 'US_BATY_20240316.zip', 'ZW_XZIM_20240322.zip']
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you have the format of files always exactly like presented:

```
files = [
    "AE_DIFX_20240320.zip",
    "AE_DIFX_20240321.zip",
    "AE_DIFX_20240322.zip"
    "AE_BATY_20240314.zip",
    "AE_BATY_20240315.zip",
    "AE_BATY_20240316.zip"
]

results = {}
for file in files:
    key, date  = file[0:7], int(file[8:16])
    if key not in results: results[key] = [date]
    else: results[key].append(date)

for key in results:
    print(key + '_' + str(max(results[key])) + '.zip')
```

The output would be then like following:

```
AE_DIFX_20240322.zip
AE_BATY_20240316.zip
```

I assume you know how to get the list of files (os.listdir)